# Firefox Add-on SDK extension with Websocket doesn't work for Facebook/Twitter

Tags: firefox, websocket, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-security-policy

I'm developing a Firefox extension based on Addon SDK.
Inside my content script, I need to create WebSocket connection to my localhost server using wss. 
In my addon script (index.js), I use "sdk/tabs" to inject content script.

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.on("ready", function(tab){
     var worker = tab.attach({
         contentScriptFile: ["./websocket.js"]
     });
});
```

data/websocket.js looks like:

```
websocket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8443/WebsocketServer/");
websocket.onopen = function(evt){
                       console.log("connection open");
                       websocket.send("connection established!");
                   };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt){
                          console.log("message received: "+evt.data);
                   };
```

I open firefox and open a page with `https://localhost:8443/` and accept the certificate. So the certificate won't be a problem here.

I can open a normal http page and this addon works perfectly, talks to my websocket server. Also I can make it work if I open `https://google.com`.
But when I open `https://www.facebook.com` or `https://www.twitter.com`, the websocket connection cannot be established.

When I turn on developer console, i can see error message:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a 
resource at wss://localhost:8443/WebsocketServer/ ("connect-src 
https://graph.facebook.com https://*.giphy.com https://pay.twitter.com 
https://analytics.twitter.com https://media.riffsy.com 
https://upload.twitter.com https://api.mapbox.com https://twitter.com").


Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a   
resource at wss://localhost:8443/WebsocketServer/ ("connect-src    
https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net 
https://*.spotilocal.com:* https://*.akamaihd.net wss://*.facebook.com:* 
https://fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* https://*.atlassolutions.com 
https://attachment.fbsbx.com ws://localhost:* blob:").
```

After I check, find facebook and twitter both implement the content script policy in their http header: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy

But I think this policy should be exempted for addon. How could I bypass this check and make my websocket connection also work on facebook and twitter also?

I found there is one link that uses XPCOMM to hyjack http header and bypass the CSP check, but this is not I'm looking for, as XPCOMM will be deprecated by firefox. Is there a more proper way of doing this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try setting those domains like mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts). Not sure though whether it will work, never tried that with web sockets.

Comment: I think a possible solution might be to create the connection in a page-worker instead of a content script. Not sure how applicable that is in your case, but it would remove any variables like CSP.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I actually added the domain to package.json, as the link @Jakub mentioned. But it doesn't work.

Comment: For @humanoid method, I thought about it, but because page-worker is only one-thread, however my extension need to monitor all tabs and send message to server, it might be a bottleneck for performance.

Comment: @HuangQiVictor it should be no problem, since it's all handled via events, so they just get queued up and at worst it takes a few seconds until the message is sent for a certain page. You could also spawn a page-worker per page, but that sounds very resource hungry.

Comment: @humanoid, thanks. It is worth a try.  But I think I should file a ticket to Firefox, basically I feel Content Security Policy shouldn't affect addon as Addons are signed by FF and should be trusted.  It doesn't make sense Addon websocket connection is blocked by website itself.

Comment: @HuangQiVictor yes, the CSP should not affect it, however it does for now so you have to work around it... (any maybe it even results in a cleaner architecture, but that's a different topic). Not sure if it's fixed for webext content scripts, but that's the place such an issue is likely to be fixed for now.